# Soft Input pans view but not enough to show full editText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a somewhat complicated layout, but at the very bottom is a huge EditText.  When I click on it to get the keyboard to open, everything slides up just enough to show exactly where the user is typing (as the user begins typing only 1 line is visible, if the user goes to multiple lines then it pans a little more to show 2 lines, etc). I would like everything to pan so that the whole EditText (all the blank space) is visible.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/CommentBox"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences|textShortMessage|textAutoCorrect|textNoSuggestions">
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Been struggling with this for a couple days now, would appreciate any suggestions.

Best way to illustrate is with 3 images

This is what the entire screen looks like

[image: This is what the entire screen looks like]

This is what the behavior is right now

[image: This is what the behavior is right now]

This is the desired behavior

[image: This is the desired behavior]

Hopefully the images illustrate my question.  I need to figure out how to make this happen. The only way I have been able to force view to pan to the right place is by setting, android:gravity to bottom , in which case text is written at the bottom. This however, is clearly a very weird user experience.  I need text to be like in a normal text box.

Comment: Maybe you can expand a bit on the question, it's not very clear to me what you want...

Comment: I updated the question with a little more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to hack together a solution that mimics what I was looking for.
Put the layout inside a scrollView, set the parameter to adjustResize instead of adjustPan. And on click in the editText did

```
scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                public void run() { 
                    scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollView.getBottom()); 
                } 
            } , 250);
```

Would love to find a non-hacky way to do this, but this is all I've got.